# How do you open a file in gtkdialog using bash

Tags: bash, gtk

I am attempting to open a config file for editing with geany by pressing a button within a gtkdialog form. I am new to bash and gtkdialog but would appreciate a push in the right direction.

```
#! /bin/bash

processconfig () {

    geany config

}
export script='
<vbox>
<hbox>
<button>
  <input file>settings_VV_small.png</input>
  <variable>button1</variable>
</button>                    
</hbox>
</vbox>    
'

I=$IFS;
IFS='
'
for STATEMENTS in  $(gtkdialog --program=script); do
      eval $STATEMENTS
done 

if [[ $BUTTON1 == "true" ]]

    then
        echo "Opening Config File"
        processconfig 
    fi


IFS=$I

[ $EXIT = sure ]
```

Comment: This works  'code'                                                                                                                 if [ "$EXIT" = "OK" ]; then
     echo "Opening Config File"
   processconfig 
 else
     echo "You pressed the Cancel button." 
 fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is your Linux Distribution, but gtkdialog in Debian is no longer available and has been removed from Debian at 2009 with reason ["unmaintained, better alternatives libraries".](https://packages.qa.debian.org/g/gtkdialog/news/20091208T170315Z.html)

Talking about "better alternatives" nowdays we have yad (apt-get install yad) , which is a fork of zenity but much more advanced.

As a result, your whole script can be replaced by two lines:

```
$ filetoopen=$(yad --file)
$ geany ""$filetoopen"
```

Studying the yad man pages, you will find million of options to tweak this gtk tool and customize your dialogs.

You can have an idea about yad dialogs here: http://smokey01.com/yad/

Comment: Thanks I will look at yad.

Comment: @Newbe I am sure that you will enjoy it!!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

```
if [ "$EXIT" = "OK" ]; then
 echo "Opening Config File"
        processconfig 
else
 echo "You pressed the Cancel button." 
fi
```

Comment: I like people who try and solve their own problems. ++1